# Scipy Voronoi 3D geometry return each bounding face

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, voronoi, scipy-spatial

So Scipy Voronoi algorithm works relatively well for my application. In the 3D situation, a given polygon is specified by its faces. However, the Voronoi algorithm doesn't generate data in hierarchical order going from vertices to edges, then to faces and then to the polygon. It only has data for what ridges a polygon contains. How do I obtain the list of indexes of ridges a face is made of and consequentially the list of indexes of faces a polygon is made of?
The detailed output from the Voronoi algorithm in Python:

```
points  (ndarray of double, shape (npoints, ndim)) Coordinates of input points.
vertices    (ndarray of double, shape (nvertices, ndim)) Coordinates of the Voronoi vertices.
ridge_points    (ndarray of ints, shape (nridges, 2)) Indices of the points between which each Voronoi ridge lies.
ridge_vertices  (list of list of ints, shape (nridges, *)) Indices of the Voronoi vertices forming each Voronoi ridge.
regions (list of list of ints, shape (nregions, *)) Indices of the Voronoi vertices forming each Voronoi region. -1 indicates vertex outside the Voronoi diagram.
point_region    (list of ints, shape (npoints)) Index of the Voronoi region for each input point. If qhull option “Qc” was not specified, the list will contain -1 for points that are not associated with a Voronoi region.
```

Cheers.